# Globals from jest-preset are not available in tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to upgrade jest from v27 to v28. In my test files when I try to access GLOBAL_VARIABLE that is specified in jest-preset file I have this error

```
ReferenceError: GLOBAL_VARIABLE is not defined
```

package.json

```
"jest": "~28.0.0",
"ts-jest": "~28.0.0-next.3"
```

my jest-preset file looks like this

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest/legacy',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/scripts/jest/tsconfig.json',
            isolatedModules: true,
        },
        GLOBAL_VARIABLE: true
    },
},
```

When running this with jest v27 it works as expected